# Excluding windows updates in Ansible

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have an Ansible playbook that installs critical & security updates on windows:

```
---
- name: Install all security, critical updates
  win_updates:
    category_names:
      - SecurityUpdates
      - CriticalUpdates
    reject_list:
    reboot: yes
    reboot_timeout: 900
```

I want to finer tune the playbook to reject any updates that have the words Preview, * Preview*, * VMware*, and * Driver* in their names. I know that the `reject_list` parameter allows you to use an update title as a regular expression but I am unsure as to how express this for the specific names I want the updates to reject.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_updates_module.html  Each entry can either be the KB article or Update title as a regex according to the PowerShell regex rules. Did a quick research about powershell regex and tested cases on this website https://regexr.com/3c0lf. I believe  the following syntax should work but didn't try it myself.

```yaml
reject_list:
    - '.*Preview.*'
    - '.*VMware.*'
    - '.*Driver.*'
```